# PHP create Hook class with priority feature

Tags: php, hook

I have the following hook class, which works as intended

```
class Hooks {
    private $hooks;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->hooks = array('top' => '', 'bottom' => '');
    }

    function add($hook, $func)
    {
        $this->hooks[$hook][] = $func;
        return $this;
    }

    function call($hook) {
        if (array_key_exists($hook, $this->hooks)) {
            $aArgs = func_get_args();
            unset($aArgs[0]);

            foreach ($this->hooks[$hook] as $func) {
                call_user_func_array($func, $aArgs);
            }
        }
    }
}

$hook = new Hooks();
$hook->add('top', function() { echo 'TOP: First <br>'; })
     ->add('top', function() { echo 'TOP: Second <br>'; })
     ->add('bottom', function() { echo 'BOTTOM: First <br>'; });

$hook->call('top');
$hook->call('bottom');
```

The output results are:

```
TOP: First 
TOP: Second 
BOTTOM: First
```

But I would like to add priority order feature into it, so it can execute by order, so, for example adding a hook with the priority number as argument will look like:

```
$hook->add('top', function() { echo 'TOP: First <br>'; }, 10)
     ->add('top', function() { echo 'TOP: Second <br>'; }, 1)
     ->add('bottom', function() { echo 'BOTTOM: First <br>'; }, 10);
```

in this case the output will have "TOP: Second" being the first by having priority set to 1:

```
TOP: Second 
TOP: First 
BOTTOM: First
```

How can I pull this off? Thank you!

EDIT: The same hook might contain several functions with the same priority, because 10 will be the default if not assigned:

```
$hook->add('top', function() { echo 'TOP: First <br>'; }) // default priority 10
     ->add('top', function() { echo 'TOP: Second <br>'; }, 1)
     ->add('top', function() { echo 'TOP: Third <br>'; }); // default priority 10
```

which means the priority value can't be used as array key, because it will be overwritten.

Comment: Add a key to `$this->hooks[$hook]` in which store a priority, then sort array by this key.

Comment: @u_mulder That won't work, because the same hook may contain several functions with the same priority.

Comment: Then add functions with same priority to an array: `$this->hooks['TOP'] = array( 1 => array($func1, $func2) , 20 => array($func3, $func4));`

Comment: @u_mulder It will be 3D array, yes, that makes sense. Wasn't thinking beyond 2D. This is the correct answer :)